# How to convince my professor to let me pass when I got less than the required score in just one aspect of grading

Tags: university, homework, course-evaluation

There are various assessments and you need to get a grade of over 50% in each. i wasn’t able to do that in one of them (I came close) although my overall grade is good. How can I convince my teacher to pardon me?

Comment: Why didn't you? Disability? Extenuating circumstances? Or did you simply not study enough?

Comment: Not all situations are pardonable. Not all professors will accept your excuses.

Answer (score 7):

Extenuating circumstances exist, and need to be taken into account. However, when they occur you need to tell your instructor as quickly as possible. That way something can be done about it. Dealing with difficult circumstances is about creating an environment where students can show what they can do. If you inform your instructor after a test, then you don't give the instructor the opportunity to do that. All they can do now is lower the standard, which is in nobody's interest.

Comment: In some places, extenuating circumstances are handled by a special admin team, not by course instructors.

Answer (score 6):

All graded courses involve drawing a line between pass and fail.  There is always some degree of arbitrarity in exactly where to draw this line, but having drawn it, it is generally good educational practice for academics to hold this line to avoid eroding academic standards.  If there are genuine extenuating circumstances then you can put in a formal application for "special consideration" and it will be considered.  However, the mere fact that you were close to a pass does not itself justify moving your grade (and hence, we will decline to assist you to convince your professor to pass you).

Rather than seeking a change in your marks, it would be a good idea for you to review your work in the course, identify the shortcomings that have led you to a failing grade, and do some additional study to remedy those shortcomings.  If you learn the material better it will allow you to pass (or hopefully do even better) the next time you do this course.  You should remember that this failing grade serves a valuable diagnostic purpose --- it tells you that you are not yet competent enough in this subject for the requirements of your degree program.  Take that diagnosis seriously and read it as an indicator that you need to give more attention to this subject.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be possible to get a "pass", but there is something you might be able to do in some places and with some professors.

Go have a face-to-face meeting, discussing your progress and what you might be missing. Ask if there is a possibility to do something extra to make up the deficit (and improve your learning). Some people would respond positively to this, rules and fairness permitting.

But the meeting will have its own value in any case, especially if this is your major subject.

Comment: I speculated that he/she missed a major component of the course.